# Nuxt + Vue + Axios + Enviroment Variables

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, axios, nuxt.js

I am unable to provide axios a baseUrl using an enviroment variable

I am using nuxt/vue/axios

What I have is roughly:

```
// axios.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

and

```
// index.vue (front page as it appears on the client)

populateFilters () {
  Vue.axios.get('filters').then((response) => {
    this.$store.commit('data/filters', response.data)
  })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
    })
}
```

and inside nuxt.config.js

```
  // nuxt.config.js
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    extend (config, ctx) {
    // Run ESLint on save

    const envLoad = require('dotenv').config()

    if (envLoad.error){
      throw result.error
    }
  }
},
```

`console.log(process.env.BASE_URL)` prints the correnct connection string in CMD, however, in chrome web browser it outputs "undefined" and I get the following error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/filters 404 (Not Found)
```

meaning that axios (probably) defaults to `http://localhost:3000` whenever the baseUrl for axios has not been set.

**What I think the problem is**

The server/client pair that is loaded up by nuxt has different contexts or that the server loads up axios before the enviroment variables have been loaded

**What I need**

I need to be able to either:

1. create .env files that contains (amongst other things) the BASE_URL
2. define these enviroment variables somewhere in the code (`nuxt.config.js` ?)

**Solution**
Please see the accepted answer

In addition, install nuxtjs/dotenv

```
npm install @nuxtjs/dotenv
```

and make your `nuxt.config.js` look like:

```
  // nuxt.config.js
  require('dotenv').config()

  module.exports = {

  modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
      '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
}
```

note that `require('dotenv').config()` must be at the top

Comment: See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/

Comment: that is exactly what I have been doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a nuxt axios module you can use. You can declare it in the module sectiont of your nuxt.config.js so you dont need your file axios.js. This is described here https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage

By loading it in the modules in the nuxt.config.js file you will have your axios instance accesible with this.$axios in your components.

You can declare the base url in the nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    ['@nuxtjs/axios', {
      baseURL: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    }]
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },
```

For "other environement variables" you can use the vuex store to have them available to all components.

Comment: Code now works and a nice improvement to the structure of the code, excellent thank you

Comment: @Pjotr Do you know how to use an instance of a plugin from Axios to handle errors, I'm trying to use SweetAlert to show an alert error when requests to server fail but Just calling it dows not work.